# PLSQL function wont return salary where name of the employee is passed in as a parameter

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-function

Here is my PLSQL function:

```
Create or Replace FUNCTION getEmpSalary(p_name in VARCHAR)
Return NUMBER IS

    l_return_salary;
    l_salary;
    table_salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
         Select salary into table_salary from AlphaCoEmp where p_name = p_name;
     return l_return_salary;
END;
/
show errors;
```

I have built a table that holds the following tuples:

```
NAME              TITLE            SALARY
------------------------- --------------------
Wong                            91296
Utech                           82058
Vega                            86858
Weiser                          79771
```

and am trying to write a PLSQL function to return the salary where the name is passed as parameter.

This is how I am passing as parameter: Note: *param1* is the name chosen.

```
exec setEmpSalary(Utech);
```

I am getting the following error(s):

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 20:
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTECH' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am unsure as to how this error is being created and could use some help fixing the error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That `CREATE FUNCTION` won't compile, you declare variables without type (`l_return_salary` and `l_salary`). Is this the actual code? I don't think so. Then you want to pass a string literal in your call, so you must enclose it in single quotes. `EXEC` is for execution of procedures not functions. And you've misspelled the name (`set` vs `get`). Try `SELECT getEmpSalary('UTECH') FROM dual;`. But I guess it won't give you anything as `=` is usually case sensitive ('UTECH' vs. 'Utech'). If you want case insensitive matching use `upper()` (or `lower()`) on both sides of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with your calling code -- `UTECH` needs to be declared -- or you need to put single quotes around it.

More importantly, the code for the function is wrong, because it confuses a parameter name and a column name.

I think you want:

```
Create or Replace FUNCTION getEmpSalary (in_p_name in VARCHAR)
Return NUMBER IS
    l_return_salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
     Select salary into l_return_salary
     from AlphaCoEmp ace
     where ace.p_name = in_p_name;
     return(l_return_salary);
END;
```

Comment: Utech is employee's name, @Gordon, it is not a *variable* :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you might/should have done:

First, a test case:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (ename  varchar2(10),
  3     salary number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (ename, salary)
  2    select 'Wong' , 91296 from dual union
  3    select 'Utech', 82058 from dual;

2 rows created.
```

A function:

- note the way I declared the parameter and the return value - both of them use the appropriate datatype of the column they reference
- I used the MAX function when selecting the salary. Why? Because, if you pass an invalid employee name, function would return NO_DATA_FOUND error. Another - and probably a better way - is to handle that with the EXCEPTION section, such as

  ```
  begin
    select ...
  exception
    when no_data_found then return null;
  end;
  ```

  Though, MAX is a *quick and dirty* solution that saves you from some typing during the testing phase of your code.

---

```
SQL> create or replace function get_emp_salary(p_ename in test.ename%type)
  2    return test.salary%type
  3  is
  4    retval test.salary%type;
  5  begin
  6    select max(t.salary)
  7      into retval
  8      from test t
  9      where t.ename = p_ename;
 10
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

OK, let's see what it does:

```
SQL> select get_emp_salary('Utech') from dual;

GET_EMP_SALARY('UTECH')
-----------------------
                  82058

SQL> select get_emp_salary('Littlefoot') from dual;

GET_EMP_SALARY('LITTLEFOOT')
----------------------------


SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

In your function, there are 3 local variables. The first two of them are invalidly declared (no datatype). `SELECT` then selects salary into "table_salary", but you're returning "l_return_salary" which is always NULL - why did you do that?

As of the error you got ("PLS-00201: identifier 'UTECH' must be declared"), it means that you passed the parameter value without single quotes, as you're passing employee **name** (which is a string).

Also, you're executing **set**EmpSalary, while the function is **get** (was it a typo?).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Create or Replace FUNCTION getEmpSalary(p_name in VARCHAR)
Return NUMBER IS
    l_return_salary number;
BEGIN
    Select salary
      into l_return_salary
     from AlphaCoEmp
    where name = p_name;
     return l_return_salary;
exception
when others then 
   return 0;
END;
```